# Why no hat on reputation league page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2012

BalusC seems to be the only high rep user to have a hat on [the reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2012-10-01/263525#263525).

None of the other users seem to have one and more importantly I don't have mine.

Why ?

Wouldn't it be cool to have the hats on the most important page of Stack Overflow ?

<sub>It's the most important page ? Yes ?</sub>

Comment: That's not a winter bash hat. It's the profile pic... You will note from his profile that he has not earned such a hat.

Comment: @Oded Damn... I thought it was obvious enough I knew it... I should learn to be less subtle :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We opted to keep the hats off of the main stackexchange.com page for two reasons:

1. That page simply isn't as trafficked as well as it could/should be.
2. Assuming it *is* used as a landing page, it should align closer with our usual tone (*we are awesome, check out our cool people and our sweet answers!*) rather than with our more relaxed tone for this event.

Beyond that, it's a consistency thing: we generally don't advertise other promos on the main Stack Exchange site, either.

Comment: Well done and well said.

Answer (score 5):

There are *no* winter bash hats on the leagues.

BalusC has a custom Gravatar with a christmas hat, he made it himself:

[image]

Others have gotten into the spirit of Juletime too:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]